# Prove by vector method that $p_1+p_2=p_3$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be an acute angled triangle whose incenter and centroid are respectively $I$ and $G$.$AI,BI$ and $CI$ cuts the sides of the triangle at $P,Q,R$ respectively.If $p_1,p_2$ and $p_3$ are the lengths of the altitudes through $A,B$ and $C$ respectively and $G$ lies on $PQ$ then prove by vector method that $p_1+p_2=p_3$.

I could not much do about this complex problem which i could mention here.I know that incenter,orthocenter and centroid all lie on one line

Comment: *incenter, orthocenter and centroid all lie on one line* - No, they don't. You're confusing incenter with circumcenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [trilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_coordinates), we have $I=[1;1;1]$ and $G=\left[\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{1}{c}\right]=[h_a;h_b;h_c]$, so:
$$ P=[0;1,1],\quad Q=[1;0;1] $$
and $G$ lies on $PQ$ iff $\det[G,P,Q]=0$. Since:
$$\det\begin{pmatrix}h_a & h_b & h_c \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=h_a+h_b-h_c$$
the claim trivially follows.

Comment: How are the trilinear coordinates of P, Q and G found?

Comment: @diya: Very well-known facts: the distances of $G$ from the side lengths are obviously $h_a/3,h_b/3,h_c/3$. Moreover, $A=[1,0,0]$, $I=[1,1,1]$ and $P=[0,?,?]$ have to be collinear, hence $P=[0,1,1]$.